# Filezilla not showing on alt-tab

Tags: unity, filezilla

I have latest Filezilla: 3.5.2

After the launch, when I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> Filezilla is icon is not present on switcher nor in the unity launcher (once I switch to other app I can't switch back).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same problem here in my Ubuntu 11.10 box. Last year the FileZilla main developer was told about Filezilla Unity integration, but it said that he does not want to do it becasue he does not use Unity at all. However, he will accept patches, he said, but may be none has done one at this time yet.

You can see the thread here:
http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21610

So I think this problem has only solution: get rid of Unity, or get rid of Filezilla.